Question about plotting graph in mathematica
I want to plot the graphs of the following system of two simultaneous equations on the (alpha 1, alpha 2) axis.
Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] == Sqrt[(Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*(1 - \[Lambda]))/(2*(1 - \[Lambda] + \[Lambda]*Subscript[\[Theta], 1]))]


Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] == 1/2 - (Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]*\[Lambda]*Subscript[\[Theta], 2])/(1 - \[Lambda])

Since Mathematica does not plot with undefined constants, I assume theta 1 = 0.5, theta 2 = 0.5, lambda =0.5
My question is: how can I plot the graphs of these two equations? I want to find the intersection of these two graphs. Also, should I use the inverse function of the alpha 1 in order to plot the graph of alpha 1?

Please check document of ContourPlot.

Subscript[\[Theta], 1] = 0.5;
Subscript[\[Theta], 2] = 0.5;
\[Lambda] = 0.5;
eq1 = Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] == 
  Sqrt[(Subscript[\[Alpha], 
       2]*(1 - \[Lambda]))/(2*(1 - \[Lambda] + \[Lambda]*
         Subscript[\[Theta], 1]))];
eq2 = Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] == 
  1/2 - (Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]*\[Lambda]*
      Subscript[\[Theta], 2])/(1 - \[Lambda]);

sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], 
    Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]}];

ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eq1, eq2},
 {Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], -3, 3}, {Subscript[\[Alpha], 2], -3, 3}
 , FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(1\)]\)", 
    Bold, 12], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Alpha]\), \(2\)]\)", Bold, 12]}
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]
   , Point@{Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]} /. sol
   }
 ]



